# Android trims the rest of the deep link URI after ampersand

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, hook, deep-linking

I'm trying to add  yet another deep link to my android application, I want my URI to look like this : **my_app://photos?id=147619727001201&edit=true**. The problem is that the system doesn't recognize this URI, so I just get trimmed version of it (**my_app://photos?id=147619727001201**). I'm just curious how android system treats deep links, and if there is any way to make this URI work. I wan't to mention that everything works fine for my other URIs, which don't contain ampersand. Here is my intent filter :

```
               <intent-filter android:label="My Item">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data
                        android:path="/photos"
                        android:pathPattern="\?"
                        android:scheme="my_app" />
                </intent-filter>
```

And here is my activity's on create method :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Uri target = getIntent().getData();
    }
```

after the following command :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my_app://photos?id=170262497002201&edit=true"
```

I get **my_app://photos?id=170262497002201** in *target.toString();*

Comment: Have you tried replacing ampersand with `&amp;`?

Comment: when I try to replace ampersand with &amp; the string after ampersand is being trimmed as I described above. I've also tried to replace it with amp; but the behavior is the same anything after amp; is being trimmed.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this command instead:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my_app://photos?id=170262497002201%26edit=true"
```

The problem is bug in platform tools version 21 
[bug issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=76026)

Comment: Gad i could help. Maybe update to version 22 will fix the problem but thats a guess

Comment: with adb version 1.0.36 I had to escape the ampersand with a backslash: e.g. `a=1\&b=2`

Answer (score 9):

You can also try escaping the '&' character  by adding a '\' before it

For example:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "fantasticapp://www/?cc=de\&tagset=123" robertoduran.isthegreatest
```